# Optional Parameter without constants

Tags: vb.net, function, parameters, option-type

I was wondering how I canspecify a Optional Parameter with a non-constant value?
Liek this for example:

```
Private Sub Foo(Optional ByVal Name as String = Application.ExecutablePath)
    MsgBox("name: " & Name)
End Sub
```

is there a workarround? 
So I can use a not constant value in the parameter as optional?

Comment: That's not possible, defaults must be values that are known at compile time.  A call to this method is rewritten to use the default value when it is compiled, not when it is executed.  Writing the method to use a default of Nothing is a simple workaround.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a workarround?

Yes:

```
Private Sub Foo(Optional ByVal Name As String = Nothing)
    If Name Is Nothing Then
        Name = Application.ExecutablePath
    End If
    MsgBox("name: " & Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: perfect thats the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way would be to avoid the `Optional` statement alltogether and use function overloading instead. This means you define a function with the same name multiple times with different declaration like so:

```
Private Sub Foo()
    Foo(Application.ExecutablePath)
End Sub
Private Sub Foo(ByVal Name as String)
    MsgBox("name: " & Name)
End Sub
```

That way, you can either supply a name or not when you call the function. The correct function is used depending on the declaration you use.
This approach seems more complicated, and in this simple case it probably is. However when your declaration gets more complicated, with more optional parameters in different orders mixed with non-optional parameters you will quickly learn to appreciate the possibilities of Overloading, I guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Tim's correct answer

This code can be made more concise by using the `If` operator.  This gives a one line setting of the alternate value if the parameter is `Nothing`

```
Private Sub Foo(Optional ByVal Name As String = Nothing)
    Name = If(Name, Application.ExecutablePath)
    MsgBox("name: " & Name)
End Sub
```

The `If` operator was introduced in 2010 IIRC so this code won't work in older versions of Visual Studio

Comment: I disagree. That is totally unnecessary. You're re-assigning a value to the variable `Name` when it's already assigned to it. Tim's answer can still be converted to one line using this: `If Name Is Nothing Then Name = Application.ExecutablePath`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it to an unused/reserved constant and then check for that in the method.

```
Private Sub(Optional ByVal Name as String = Nothing)
  If Name Is Nothing Then Name = Application.ExecutablePath
  MsgBox("name: " & Name)
End Sub
```

For some extra niceties, you can use xml comments and attributes to indicate via intellisense what the real "default" value is.